# variável não consegue admitir outro valor

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input("jogadas:"))

a=22695477
b=1
m=2**32 
semente=3 
i=1
num=None
num_aleatorio = None
lance_computador = None
while i <= n:
    lance_jogador=int(input("Faça sua jogada"))
    if i==1:
        num = semente
    else:
        num = num_aleatorio

    num_aleatorio = (num*a + b)%m 
    print(num_aleatorio)
    if num_aleatorio <= m//2:
        lance_computador == 0
    else:
       lance_computador == 1
    semente = num_aleatorio
    i = i + 1

    if lance_jogador != lance_computador:
            print("Jogador ganha!")
            print(lance_jogador, "jogador,", lance_computador,"máquina.")
    elif lance_jogador == lance_computador:
            print("Máquina ganha!")
            print(lance_jogador, "jogador,", lance_computador,"máquina.")
```

eu precisei definir a variável `lance_computador` como `None` para começar o programa, mas a partir desse momento, ela não consegue admitir os valores colocados no `if/else`. como proceder?

Comment: Em vez de `lance_computador == 0` tenta `lance_computador = 0` d:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está atribuindo lance_computador com == em vez de =.